# C# - How do you return a Type based off of a string

Tags: c#, .net

For example, I have a class called Clothing that inherits from a abstract class of Product.

```
public class Clothing : Product
{
    public bool IsInSeason {get; set;}
    public string Material {get; set; }
    public Decimal IsFeatured { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit:** 
In a function, how would I be able to pass the string "Clothing" and have a typeof the class returned?

```
ReturnTypeOfClassBasedOffOfString(string class)
{
    // ... 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Type.GetType(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx)

Note that sometime the class name won't be enough. Sometime you will need to provide the [AssemblyQualifiedName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx)

*"If the type is in the currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name qualified by its namespace."*

Comment: In my case, how can I provide the AssemblyQualifiedName to Type.GetType?  AssemblyQualifiedName requires known the Type :O

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Type.GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) for that, but: what do you want to achieve? I can bet you need something simpler. Why do we need the `Clothing` class at all?

BTW: `ReturnTypeOfClassBasedOffOfString(string class)` wouldn't compile. You need either `ReturnTypeOfClassBasedOffOfString(string classname)` or `ReturnTypeOfClassBasedOffOfString(string @class)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
static Type ReturnTypeOfClassBasedOffOfString(string className)
{
  foreach (Assembly a in AppDomain.Current.GetAssemblies ())
  {
    foreach (Type t in a.GetTypes ())
    {
      if (t.Name == className) // Ignore namespace
        return t;
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

Comment: I think it is a good solution for those who don't want to worry about the namespace. But in terms of performance it is way better to provide the Assembly qualified name.

Comment: Or if you know the assembly: 
`Assembly assem = Assembly.LoadFrom("assemblyname.dll"); assem.GetTypes().Single(t => t.Name == className);` 

Also, be careful how you abbreviate "assembly"... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Type.GetType("MyApplication.Product", true)
```

for this purpose but you must include the namespace ("MyApplication", for example).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get type the:

```
Type.GetType
```

is enough.and if you want to create instance using it's stringy name you should use

```
Activator.CreateInstance
```

GoodLuck