# C# - How do you return a Type based off of a string where the type resides in a different assembly

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-4.0

This is extending what I had previously asked in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322522/c-how-do-you-return-a-type-based-off-of-a-string) question.  I can use the Type.GetType(mystring) to return a type based on the string I pass.  The problem is that the type that I want to determine is in a different assembly.

How can I return the type based on a string, where the type resides in a different assembly.

**Edit:** I have a method that accepts a string, the string is the type that I want to return.  I'd like to not have to hard-code the assembly into the method if possible...

Answer (score 2):

You could specify the assembly assuming it is already loaded into the app domain:

```
var stringType = Type.GetType("System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089", true);
```

If it isn't you might need to load the assembly first:

```
var myType = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"c:\work\MyAssembly.dll").GetType("Foo.Bar", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Type.GetType(...)` can do this, you just have to pass in the namespace-qualified type name: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to know what assembly the type resides in, so that you can then access that assembly.

Once you have that, you can use the System.Reflection components to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx

Something like

```
Type t = Assembly.Load("myassembly").GetType("myType");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the fully qualified assembly name:

This will get the type `ViewPage` in the System.Web.Mvc assembly:

```
Type.GetType(System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35)
```